# Is it possible to conditionally compile a code block inside a function?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I'm wondering if something like this is possible

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(foo)] {
        println!("using foo config");
    }

}
```

The context is some code that cannot adequately be tested with just unit tests. I'll often have to run a "demo" cfg which displays information. I'm looking for alternatives to manually commenting in/out some portions of code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of at least Rust 1.21.1, it's possible to do this as exactly as you said (however, *only inside of functions*):

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(foo)]
    {
        println!("using foo config");
    }
}
```

---

Before this, it isn't possible to do this completely conditionally (i.e. avoiding the block being type checked entirely), doing that is covered by [RFC #16](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/16). However, you can use the `cfg` macro which evaluates to either `true` or `false` based on the `--cfg` flags:

```
fn main() {
    if cfg!(foo) { // either `if true { ... }` or `if false { ... }`
        println!("using foo config");
    }
}
```

The body of the `if` always has name-resolution and type checking run, so may not always work.

Comment: Note that you can only use blocks like this inside a function, not at the top level of a file. There is some discussion as to why in this closed RFC issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2377

Answer (score 2):

You may interested in the crate [**cfg-if**](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/latest/cfg_if/), or a simple macro will do:

```
macro_rules! conditional_compile {
    ($(#[$ATTR:meta])* { $CODE: tt }) => {
        {
            match 0 {
                $(#[$ATTR])*
                0 => $CODE,

                // suppress clippy warnning `single_match`.
                1 => (),
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    conditional_compile{
        #[cfg(foo)]
        {{
            println!("using foo config");
            // Or something only exists in cfg foo, like a featured mod.
        }}
    }
}
```