# Can cfg!() contexts be aware of [#cfg()]-scoped modules?

Tags: testing, rust, compilation, macros, mocking

Is there a way to get `cfg!()` to conditionally call a function in a module that's only defined when the expression in `cfg!()` is true?

For example, here's an attempt to use a test-only deterministic replacement for `ThreadRng.fill_bytes()`:

```rust
use rand::RngCore;
fn main() {
    let mut dst = [0u8, 0, 0, 0];
    if cfg!(test) {
        test::fill_bytes(&mut dst);
    } else {
        rand::thread_rng().fill_bytes(&mut dst);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    pub fn fill_bytes(dst: &mut [u8]) {
        for i in dst {
            *i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `test`
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         test::fill_bytes(&mut dst);
  |         ^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `test`
```

I had expected the compiler to do a pass that includes `[#cfg(test)]` calls first, so it would know that `test::fill_bytes()` was defined, and then do a pass that evaluates `cfg!()`, but apparently that's not how it works.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: no, you cannot use the macro for this.

Comment: Ah, thanks, not sure how I missed that question in my searching. What I wasn't aware of is that `cfg!()` evaluates at runtime.

Comment: Ah, but following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396422/79202), I can use the block form: `#[cfg(test)]\n{ tests::fill_bytes(rb); }\n\n #[cfg(not(test))]\n{ rand::thread_rng().fill_bytes(rb); }`

Comment: Yep, that alternative is shown in the linked duplicate ("You can also use the attribute form of `cfg`..."). You don't need the braces in this case since you only have a single function call